Customizer works with property but not with propertyExpression
Customizing barChart with RangeAxisCustomizer works when using property, but not working when using propertyExpression. Tried like <![CDATA[0.00]] and <![CDATA["0.00"]] .
Actually I need to set the value of propertyExpression like <![CDATA[$P{maxRangeValue}]] and it was not working so I tried to pass hard code value, still fails.
Works
<barChart>
        <chart evaluationTime="Report">
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="83074c0b-30e8-4c98-bfc1-94ba36a4a955">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.customizer.class.1" value="com.test.invoice.web.chart.customizer.BarColorCustomizer"/>                                 
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.customizer.class.0" value="net.sf.jasperreports.customizers.axis.RangeAxisCustomizer"/>
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.customizer.0.minValue" value="0.0"/>
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.customizer.0.maxValue" value="70000.0"/>
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.customizer.0.tickUnit" value="10000.0"/>
            </reportElement>

Not Working
<barChart>
    <chart evaluationTime="Report">
        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" backcolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="83074c0b-30e8-4c98-bfc1-94ba36a4a955">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.customizer.class.1" value="com.test.invoice.web.chart.customizer.BarColorCustomizer"/>                                 
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.customizer.class.0" value="net.sf.jasperreports.customizers.axis.RangeAxisCustomizer"/>
        <propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.customizer.0.minValue"><![CDATA["0.00"]]></propertyExpression>
        <propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.customizer.0.maxValue"><![CDATA["70000.00"]]></propertyExpression>
        <propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.customizer.0.tickUnit"><![CDATA["10000.00"]]></propertyExpression>
        </reportElement>
                                

